# Deriving and applying the cosine law

Tags: trigonometry

A brake lever for a crane is 0.9 meters long and hinged at its base. To fully activate brake, the top end of the lever must move 0.4m horizontally. Through what angle must the lever rotate?

Comment: brake?  break?  level?  lever?  Should they be the same?  It is probably hinged at its base.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Have you drawn a picture?  You have a right triangle, with hypotenuse $0.9$ and one leg $0.4$.